# Using Jasmine on an existing AngularJS / Bootstrap project no module found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, jasmine

So I have an existing group project that needs to have test coverage. The project is using npm and angularJS. I began by doing an npm install on jquery, as well as jasmine, and angular-mocks. I thought a good, simple place to start (not much testing experience) would be with the routing. I have some very basic routing defined here

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", 
        {   templateUrl: "partials/home/home.html", 
            controller: "PageCtrl"
        })
    // else 404
    .otherwise("/404", 
        {   templateUrl: "partials/404.html", 
            controller: "PageCtrl"
        });
}]);
```

and I began to write tests. started with a very simple example obtained online

```
describe('Route testing', function () {

  beforeEach(module('tutorialWebApp'));


  it('should route accordingly', inject( function ($route) {
    expect($route.routes['/'].controller).toBe('PageCtrl');
    expect($route.routes['/'].templateUrl).toEqual('partials/home/home.html');
  }));
});
```

I am getting a type error: module is not a function, pointing to my beforeEach line. I researched this problem and none of the solutions I found have made me any progress. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**beforeEach** accepts a callback functions. Your code is calling the *module* function which obviously doesn't return a function. Your call to module must be wrapped inside a callback function. Something like this:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    module('tutorialWebApp');

    // some other code
});
```

Comment: Still says module is not a function.

Comment: Nope. [Angular guide for unit testing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) suggests the way OP's posted in question is correct.